# How to use AWS CLI with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

In the documentation it states that the EB CLI is replaced by AWS CLI but all of the documentation is still talking about EB CLI.

I have created an application in Elastic Beanstalk console and now I'm ready to start developing. I have all the tools installed on Ubuntu and I've already tested it locally. Now I want to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. How do I do this with AWS CLI?

Comment: Have you gone through this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html

Comment: After you install aws cli, you will have to execute commands using `aws cli elasticbeanstalk check-dns-availability <options>`

Comment: Also check this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-aws-cli.html

Comment: Where in the documentation did you read about AWS CLI replacing EB CLI? I couldn't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 43):

You have to create a source bundle from your application, see details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html (Or alternatively you can use [AWS CodeCommit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/welcome.html) or [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) as source for your application.)

Then you can use the AWS CLI to create a new version from your application and deploy it to one application environment. (See the CLI documentation for EBS [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html#cli-aws-elasticbeanstalk).)

---

Create a source bundle:

```
zip MyCodeBundle.zip <source files>
```

Upload that to S3:

```
aws s3 cp MyCodeBundle.zip s3://a-bucket-where-you-store-your-source-bundles/
```

[Create a new application version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-application-version.html) using the source bundle you just uploaded:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name YourEBSAppName --version-label YourVersionLabel --source-bundle S3Bucket="a-bucket-where-you-store-your-source-bundles",S3Key="MyCodeBundle.zip"
```

And finally you [update one of your environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html) to use that version (this is *deploy* even though that verb is completely missing from the new [AWS CLI for EBS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html#cli-aws-elasticbeanstalk) - this was a little confusing for me):

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name YourEBSAppName --environment-name YourEBSEnvironmentName --version-label YourVersionLabel
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a way to deploy to EB without the weird git integration stuff Amazon provides. This is a bit longer than I hoped, but it works.

Comment: If you are trying to run this through Github actions, you need to add region flag. 
"--region us-east-1"

Comment: Can you pls help me with this - How would I know if the environment deployment is completed? since even after aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment is success- deployment is still being processed in aws

Comment: I got this error with **create-application-version** command `An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateApplicationVersion operation: No Application named 'hello-world' found. `

Comment: Also, currently **create-application-version** don't create the environment

Answer (score 2):

To complement @qqbenq answer, here is an example of AWS CLI deployment to beanstalk with a given [deployment policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkcommand):

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
    --environment-name <eb-env-name> \
    --version-label <verion-label-to-deploy> \
    --option-settings \
        Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:command,OptionName=DeploymentPolicy,Value=Rolling \
        Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:command,OptionName=BatchSizeType,Value=Fixed \
        Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:command,OptionName=BatchSize,Value=1
```

Comment: This really saved my day, all I was looking for was to update one `custom value` inside configuration. This was my final command: `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name myenvname --option-settings Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment,OptionName=CONFIGURATION_NUMBER,Value=1.2.003`

Comment: @mdabdullah Glad the answer was useful:-)